# Is it possible copy the contents of multiple widgets simultaneous in Tkinter?

Tags: python, copy, widget, tkinter

I'm trying to add a feature in python that copies the entire contents of two text widgets. How would one go about that?

Pseudo Code:

```
    text1.SelectAll()
    C1 = text1.get(Copy)

    text2.SelectAll()
    C2 = text2.get(Copy)

    Paste('Widget 1:\n\n' + C1 + 'Widget 2:\n\n' + C2 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do (if you have a `from Tkinter import *` -- I don't like it but many use it):

```
C1 = text1.get(1.0, END)
C2 = text2.get(1.0, END)
```

Now you have the two strings.  I'm not sure where that `Paste` is supposed to put the text into -- if you mean to replace the previous contents of `text2`, for example, just do

```
text2.delete(1.0, END)
text2.insert(END, "Whatever: %s and: %s" % (C1, C2))
```

To learn more about Tkinter text controls, read [this chapter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) in effbot's online Tkinter book.

Comment: you should get "end-1c" since Tk always adds an extra newline as the very last character in the text widget. using 1.0 and "end-1c" is the canonical way of getting all of the data in the widget.

Comment: @Bryan, right, if you don't want the trailing newline -- good point, fixing accordingly, thanks and +1;-).